# add multiple dropdown value to a List in flutter

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, dropdown

In my flutter app I've created a dropdown. initially there is only one dropdown but the user can add more. the items of these dropdowns are the same. but the selected results has to be different. but my code is returning the last selected value. so how can I add it on list?

Model

```
class DropModel {
  String? selected;

  DropModel({this.selected});

  setData(list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      selected = list;
    }
  }
}
```

initialize

```
List<String>? selCat;

DropModel selDrop = DropModel();
```

dropdown widget

```
DropdownButtonFormField2 _generatedDropDown(
      List<String> category, String? selected, int index) {
    final group = _GroupControllers();
    return DropdownButtonFormField2(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        isDense: true,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
      ),
      isExpanded: true,
      hint: const Text(
        'Select Category',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
      ),
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.arrow_drop_down,
        color: Colors.black45,
      ),
      iconSize: 30,
      buttonHeight: 60,
      buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
      items: category
          .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: item,
                child: Text(
                  item,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null) {
          return 'Please select Catagory.';
        }
      },
      onChanged: (value) {
        //Do something when changing the item if you want.
        setState(() {
          // selDrop.setData(value.toString());
          selected = value.toString();
          selDrop.selected = selected;
          selCat!.insert(index, selected.toString());
        });
      },
      onSaved: (value) {
        //selDrop.setData(value.toString());
        selected = value.toString();
        selDrop.selected = selected;
        selCat!.insert(index, selected.toString());
      },
    );
  }
```

result looped

```
print(".................${selDrop.selected}"); // returns the last added/ selected value
print(".................${selCat}"); //returns null
```

the traditional `List` returns null and the model returns the last added/selected value. how can i add multiple dropdown selected values to a List? each has different values. in a textfield I could create dynamic `TextEditingController` but how can I manage dropdowns